# MySQL & PHP CMS project 'JOINS'

Tags: php, mysqli, left-join

i have a project to build a CMS. We were giving a few functions.. on is below. I would like someone to explain to me what the 'p', 'ca', and 'cm' mean/stand for?

```
function getAllPosts() {

global $db;

$sql = "SELECT  p.*, ca.catName, COUNT(commentID) as numComments
        FROM    posts p
        LEFT JOIN   categorys ca USING (categoryID)
        LEFT JOIN   comments cm USING (postID)
        ";

if ($_GET['catID'] != ''){

    $catID = (int)$_GET['catID'];

    $sql .= "WHERE categoryID = $catID ";

}

$sql .= "GROUP BY postID
        ORDER BY    postDate DESC";

$qry = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$result = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

if (count($result) > 0) {
    return $result;
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: It's aliases for the table names. It's more apperant if you write the full query for it `FROM posts AS p`

Answer (score 0):

They are a shorter way to write a query without using the whole table names. (table alias)

E.g. `SELECT a.name, a.surname FROM very_long_name_of_my_table [AS] a`

instead of

`SELECT very_long_name_of_my_table.name, very_long_name_of_my_table.surname FROM very_long_name_of_my_table`

Answer (score -1):

*SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.*

*Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.*

for more visit: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp